# referenceNode.parentNode throwing undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replicate jQuery's `after()` with JavaScript:

```
var orangeBlock = '<a href="http://clo2015.chineselearnonline.com/">Try out the New Version of CLO</a></div>'
var greyBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('grey-block')

function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
  console.log(referenceNode.parentNode)
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling)
}

insertAfter(orangeBlock, greyBlock)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of undefined theme.js:62
insertAfter theme.js:62
(anonymous function)

I find it strange, since `console.log(greyBlock)` outputs the item:

```
[item: function]
0: div.grey-block
length: 1
__proto__: NodeList
```

Live site: http://www.chineselearnonline.com/amember/member.php

Comment: Well, that's a simple one: your `insertAfter` does expect **dom nodes**! Neither `orangeBlock` (a string) nor `greyBlock` (a nodelist) are nodes!!!

Comment: @ Bergi Oh, how can I get the nodes instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`orangeBlock` is a string. You need a DOM node to use `insertBefore`. You can convert it like below.

```
var orange = document.createElement('div');
orange.innerHTML = orangeBlock;
```

document.getElementsByClassName get list of nodes. So you need to select one out of them `greyBlock[0]`

Something like this finally.

```
var orangeBlock = '<a href="http://clo2015.chineselearnonline.com/">Try out the New Version of CLO</a>';
var orange = document.createElement('div');
orange.innerHTML = orangeBlock;

var greyBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('grey-block');

function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

insertAfter(orange, greyBlock[0]);
```

Comment: Weird, I'm still getting: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined`  http://www.chineselearnonline.com/amember/member.php

Comment: @alexchenco: I ran it from the console and it seems to be working. Place your `theme.js` before the body ends. Looks like the code is being executed before the dom element is even created.

Comment: You're right. Wrapping everything with `window.onload = function()` made it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your `insertAfter` function does expect DOM nodes! Neither `orangeBlock` (a string) nor `greyBlock` (a Nodelist) are nodes.

So rather do something like

```
// create an element using DOM methods
var orangeBlock = document.createElement("a");
orangeBlock.href="http://clo2015.chineselearnonline.com/";
orangeBlock.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Try out the New Version of CLO"));
 // access the first element in the node list
var greyBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('grey-block')[0];

function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
  console.log(referenceNode.parentNode)
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling)
}
if (greyBlock)
    insertAfter(orangeBlock, greyBlock)
else
    alert("could not find an element with the class 'grey-block'");
```

But actually, you'll want to use the [`insertAdjacentHTML` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('grey-block')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<a href="http://clo2015.chineselearnonline.com/">Try out the New Version of CLO</a>')
```

Comment: Ha, I'm not sure why I'm always getting `undefined`: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertAdjacentHTML' of undefined` http://www.chineselearnonline.com/amember/member.php

Comment: @alexchenco: Yes, probably [because the element doesn't exists yet](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1048572)

Comment: So how can I solve that? It does get the element with `document.getElementsByClassName('grey-block')` But gets a `NodeList`.

Comment: @alexchenco: It's mentioned there in the first answer of the linked question. Go read it.